# Query total number of sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

In ExactTarget I am trying to query the total number of sends within the last 7 for each subscriber, and only store the results where the number of 'TotalSends' is greater than 0.

Here is what I have going so far:

```
SELECT  EmailAddress, (
  SELECT count(*) FROM _Sent p
  WHERE  p.SubscriberKey = s.EmailAddress 
  AND EventDate between DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) 
AS 'TotalSent' 
FROM Master_Subscriber_DE AS s
WHERE 'TotalSent' > 0
```

I run this query and get no results.  If I remove that last line - It works, but I get ALL results (I only want the results where 'TotalSent' > 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up getting what I needed with the code below:

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalSent, p.SubscriberKey as EmailAddress
FROM _Sent p 
WHERE p.EventDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY p.SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: Looks good, but what is gained by joining Master_Subscriber_DE the only column being selected from it is EmailAddress which also exists in _Sent?

Comment: You are right Mac, nothing was gained by adding that JOIN.  Thanks so much for your help :)  I went ahead and edited my post above.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't test it, but something like this should work assuming all your subscriberkeys are email addresses

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(SubscriberKey) as TotalSent FROM _Sent
WHERE EventDate between DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(SubscriberKey) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Having clause:

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalSent, s.EmailAddress FROM _Sent p
  WHERE  p.SubscriberKey = s.EmailAddress 
  AND EventDate between DATEADD(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
group by s.EmailAddress
having count(*) > 0
```

Comment: Hi Mac - thanks so much for your reply.  When I do as you suggested, I receive this error:  

The multi-part identifier "s.EmailAddress" could not be bound.